# Docker add additional arguments to start

Tags: mongodb, docker

I created a mongo docker instance and by default it doesn't have auth enabled.

So i created a root user and a read/write user for a database, and now I want to restart it in auth mode, which is usually done by passing the `--auth` argument on startup.

Is it possible to restart the mongo docker instance with the additional flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can launch the container with an alternate command including any extra parameters:  `docker run [opts] mongodb mongod --auth`

The overall structure is `docker run [docker run options] [containername] [alternate command to run] [args for the command]`.

Comment: Nobody noticed the question was about `docker start`, not `docker run` !?